# How many API calls is a single select statement?

Tags: api

I'm using a 3rd party tool to execute a SQL select statement on one object. Is that the equivalent of using only 1 API call, or is it more?

Answer (score 2):

login() - 1 Call,
query() - 1 Call,
logout() - 1 Call,

Source: http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_calls_list.htm#topic-title

Comment: It may be more, if they don't explicitly show pagination (queryMore).